# Non self adjoint subalgebra of a C*-algebra.

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, adjoint-operators

Can you give an example of a closed (unital) non self adjoint subalgebra of a unital C*algebra?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

Take your favorite C*-algebra $A$ and an element $a\in A$ that is not self-adjoint.  Then the closed subalgebra generated by $a$ will usually not contain $a^*$, and hence will not be self-adjoint.

For an explicit example, let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ be the closed unit disk, let $A=C(D)$, and let $a\in A$ be the inclusion function $D\to\mathbb{C}$ (i.e., $a(z)=z$).  The closed subalgebra generated by $a$ is then the closure of the set of functions $D\to\mathbb{C}$ which are polynomials in $z$.  If $a^*$ were in the closed subalgebra generated by $a$, then the function $a^*(z)=\overline{z}$ would be a uniform limit of polynomials in $z$.  This is impossible by some basic complex analysis (for instance, the fact that a uniform limit of holomorphic functions is holomorphic).

Comment: My example is similar to yours. I considered the uniform closure of functions on the unit circle of the form
$$
\left\{ \begin{matrix}
\mathbb{S} & \to & \mathbb{C} \\
z & \mapsto & \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n} c_{k} z^{k}
\end{matrix} \right\},
$$
where $ c_{0},\ldots,c_{n} \in \mathbb{C} $.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, and consider the subalgebra
$$
B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\ 0&\gamma\end{bmatrix}:\ \alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb C\right\}.
$$

Comment: Nice one, Martin. That $ B $ is not closed under the adjoint operation is obvious.